# Forcing HTTPS and WWW with apache

Tags: htaccess, apache, https, mod-rewrite, cloudflare

Apache does not force HTTPS in a subfolder of a folder, but it works in the first level subfolders.

Here are all the HTAccess snippets I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Hope someone has the answer

Edit: After playing around with it some more I found part of the problem.

For example in one of the subdirectories in one of the subfolders directly under the site root, in the HTAccess file, I had this code

```
RewriteRule ^jquery_autocomplete.html$ jquery_autocomplete.php [L]
```

As soon as I add that line, for whatever reason it stops forcing HTTPS in that subdirectory, but as soon as I remove it again, HTTPS is forced.

Comment: Which version of Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider not using .htaccess. This will help with performance and avoid that other .htaccess files overwrite your conf. In your main apache .conf file you can add:

```
<Directory "YOUR WEB DIRECTORY">
   AllowOverride None
   .....
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   ....
</Directory>
```

If this is a permanent change, using 301 instead of 302 is better, 302 is temporary

Comment: I always use 302 until I test that the rule works which is when I change it to 301 but thanks for the tip anyway :)

Comment: "...avoid that other .htaccess files overwrite your conf" - Specifically, it is the `AllowOverride None` directive here that prevents `.htaccess` from "overwriting the conf" - because it disables `.htaccess` altogether. However, you can prevent `.htaccess` directives from "overwriting your conf" and still have `.htaccess` enabled, by placing these directives outside of the `<Directory>` container, directly in the _virtualhost_ or _server_ context. Or, by changing the mod_rewrite inheritance order using the `RewriteOptions` directive.

Comment: However, if you have access to the server config then you probably shouldn't be using mod_rewrite anyway for HTTP to HTTPS redirects. Instead, you should be using the simpler mod_alias `Redirect` in the appropriate VirtualHost container - unless you are behind a proxy, which is suggested by the code posted here - but that is not the case as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

> in one of the subdirectories in one of the subfolders directly under the site root, in the HTAccess file, I had this code

And that's the problem. By default, mod_rewrite does not inherit the directives from parent folders. So the mod_rewrite directives in the subfolder completely override the directives in parent folders (the directives that canonicalize the URL). In fact, simply enabling the `RewriteEngine` in the subfolder is enough to block the parent directives.

In the .htaccess file in the subdirectory you can try adding the following:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

However, you should note that mod_rewrite directives in the parent .htaccess file are applied *after* the directives in the subfolder. (Also, the inherited directives are "virtually copied" to the subfolder's .htaccess file - so they may not behave quite as expected.)

If you are on Apache 2.4+ then you have additional options. For instance, you could specify the following in the .htaccess file in your document root to inherit the parent directives for *all* subfolders .htaccess files *and* the parent directives are executed first.

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
```

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

---

In order to force HTTPS and `www` in *one rule* you can do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Similar to what you already had, but you can't use `%{HTTP_HOST` in the substitution (incidentally you are missing the closing curly brace), since this may or may not already contain the `www.` subdomain. (You might be able to use `%{SERVER_NAME}` but that is server dependent.)

The `302` (temporary) redirect is good for testing, but change this to `301` when you are happy it's working OK.

To have two separate rules then use your 3rd code block.

Comment: Thanks :) It works I just have one more question. When I add the RewriteOptions Inherit directive to the correct HTAccess file, and then remove the WWW and HTTPS from the browser's address bar, it redirects back to https: // www. domain. tld and requests the correct resource but still appends the file extension on the end. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: My Apache version is 2.4.12

Comment: Yes, that will happen unfortunately since the parent directives are run _after_ the directives in the subfolder. (You internally rewrite to the `.php` file, but then externally redirect to the correct HTTPS/www.) If you are on Apache 2.3.10+ you can change `Inherit` to `InheritBefore` to get the parent directives to execute first.

Comment: Since you are on Apache 2.4 you can try the `InheritDownBefore` option as mentioned above - note that this goes in the _parent_ .htaccess file, not the subfolder. (It inherits _down_.)

Comment: Which would you recommend, InheritBefore or InheritDownBefore

Comment: Essentially the net result should be the same. However, it depends on your site which is more appropriate. `InheritBefore` would need to be applied to every subfolder that it applies. If you have many subfolders with their own .htaccess files and you need the parent directives to apply to _all_ subfolders then you only need to specify `InheritBeforeDown` once in the root .htaccess file. To be honest, having multiple .htaccess files can be a maintenance nightmare - there is a strong argument for having just a single .htaccess file in the document root.

Comment: Thanks :) I used the solution you recommended with the line in the .htaccess file in the site root as it is less complex and applies site wide.